# Committing Each Part of Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a series of database triggers that successively clean up data. The data is scraped off of financial websites and inserted through a bulk insert. It then runs through a couple of staging tables and ends up in our "clean data" table. If a row of scraped data is well formed, then it proceeds down the pipe without any problems. If a row makes it to the "clean data" table with a NULL value, then it is rightly rejected due to NOT NULL constraints, but the entire transaction, even the original bulk insert, is rolled back. How do I "commit" every step of the transaction and write the failed fills to an Errors table?

I tried putting the final insert into the clean table into a try catch, but that doesn't help.

Comment: You can't commit part of a transaction. That violates the Atomic concept. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480356.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Filter your final insert so that it won't violate any constraints.

If a column in the final table can't be NULL, add `WHERE ThatColumn IS NOT NULL` to the INSERT..SELECT statement.

Comment: Yeah, this is the way I ended  up doing it. Before insertion into the final table, I split the data into two groups, those with no NULLS and those with a NULL value. I inserted the no NULL group and logged the NULL group.